# Is it possible to deploy an Azure resource in "dev/test" mode in order to test faster?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-resource-manager, setup-deployment

I would need to test a few scripts i wrote using the Azure CLI for deployment of Azure resources and i would like to test them fast, in order to work on the new resources in a test mode without waiting so long. Is there a way to use Azure in a test or development mode?

Comment: What do you mean by `test or development mode`?

Comment: for example an environment where deployment is faster but implemented resources are less reliable, slower, obv not covered but SLAs

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is possible, but it'd help if you listed the services you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the resources you want to use.
For IAAS(Infrastructure as a Service) virtual machines there is an option of Dev/Test Labs.

For more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devtest-lab/

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, azure doesnt offer anything like that.